# How to learn about universes in category theory?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

I have a background in analytic philosophy and AI and have developed an interest in Category theory. I am currently finishing *Conceptual Mathematics: A First Introduction to Categories*, by F. William Lawvere and Stephen H. Schanuel, which I liked because it is so accessible.

A notion that is intriguing to me is that of universes. There are some parallels to my own philosophical work and I would like to find the most accessible introduction to this topic. Any recommendations?

Comment: Please note: The words mathematicians put on these things usually do not correspond to how the word is used in everyday life.

Comment: I am aware that a universe is not a universe :D the idea is that in philosophy certain paradoxes arise if one assumes a "gods eye point of view". So one has to restrict oneself to a limited perspective. Universes in CT seem to be postulated for a similar reason: only limited domains of discourse can be coherently discussed without running into Russels paradox etc.

Comment: I kind-of feel like your question "I want to learn more about universes in category theory/set theory" is similar to "I want to learn more about salt in baking cakes". There's a lot of good books about baking cakes, and all of them do talk a bit about salt, but asking for books to learn more about salt for baking cakes is quite a specific request, and I wouldn't know what books that would be.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you study set theory for this.

It seems you understand the basic idea: you grab every set that the usual set theory lets you build, and consider a set of all those sets. This new "large" set which may be called a *grothendieck universe*, will let you build more sets out it by using the usual axioms of set theory, and then you can consider a set of all of these sets, which will give you a new universe, and so on.

Some other keywords are *large cardinal* and *inaccesible cardinal*.

---

A more formal description can be found in the wikipedia or nlab entries:

Wikipedia:

- [Tarski Grothendieck set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory)
- [Grothendieck universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe)

nLab:

- [Tarski Grothendieck set theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Tarski-Grothendieck+set+theory)
- [Grothendieck universe](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+universe)

They are also good for references, specially nlab.

---

A recommended book on the topic:

- [The higher infinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Higher_Infinite)

It may be a bit too advanced. You should read some introduction to set theory and cardinals/ordinals beforehand.

---

Finally, I'd like to add that type theory has some interesting ideas as well, and which might be easier to understand. (Maybe I'm biased here since I come from computer science, but the constructions are definitely simpler.)

[For instance here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory#Universe_types)

The original paper by Per Martin-Löf doesn't use a hierarchy, only two types "Set" and "Type" to avoid paradoxes. But maybe it's interesting and useful to you already. (Then they did extend Martin-Löf's type theory with a hierarchy of universes.)

I must add that it's not a very hard paper to read. [MLTT71](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaelt/martin-lof/master/pdfs/martin-loef1971%20-%20A%20Theory%20of%20Types.pdf)

It also occurs to me that [the HoTT book](https://hott.github.io/book/hott-online-13-g2e736d1.pdf) has a nice ~1-page informal introduction to the topic as well. In the first chapter of the book.

---

Hope this helps. Cheers!